# How to get same size of slider thumb on android like IOS in react native

Tags: react-native

```
<Slider
          style={{ width: '100%' }}
          step={15}
          onValueChange={change}
          value={travleSliderVal}
          maximumValue={120}
          thumbTintColor={colors.lightBlueRGB}
          minimumTrackTintColor={colors.lightBlueRGB}
        />
```

I do not think any prop available which can help me out.

Comment: Not sure if you are looking for reinventing the wheel, but there is dependency created already https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-slider-thumb-emoji with example

Comment: Yeah temporarily used the same.But this npm packages are not written in TS so i was facing issue in using it.